# I want my app to run in background when a message is received. How do i program it?

Tags: android, background, sms

I want my app to run in background when a message is received from any number. Please, help me with the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look for [services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)